# Python 3+ - for in range loop, multiply, product, list NOT using mul or lambda or for in loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, product

[I'm taking this online Python course](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/13-lists/#pybox11) and a common theme in this course is to NOT use functions or libraries to solve solutions. The problem asks:

> Define a function prod(L) which returns the product of the elements in a list L.

My attempt is below. This specific problem asks to use for in range, the next question uses for in. I understand how to use for in, but not for in range. How do use the range i of 0,1,2,3 to help calculate the product?

broken for in range loop:

```
def prod(L):
   Llen = len(L)
   for i in range (0,Llen):
      print(L[-1]*L[-2]*L[-3]*L[-4])

prod([1,2,3,4])
```

My for in loop works fine.

```
def prod(L):
   p = 1
   for i in L:
      p *= i
   return p

prod([1,2,3,4])
```

Please no lambda or 'from operator import mul'! I understand those methods.

Comment: You're using the `len` and `range` functions, but you can't use `enumerate`?

Comment: Meanwhile, what makes you think `print(L[-1]*L[-2]*L[-3]*L[-4])` each time through the loop is going to cause it to return the product of all of the `i` values? If your `for…in` loop works fine, why didn't you just try the exact same thing with a `for … in range(…)` loop and see what happens?

Comment: No, enumerate. I keep feeling like I have to find the most difficult and time-consuming method possible to solve the solution. I thought the for in solution was too easy, that it wouldn't have been accepted. You're right. I should have tried it.

Comment: I know that you mention that you aren't interested in lambda methods but you could actually simplify your code to one line using `reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [1, 2, 3, 4])` It might be worth looking through [lambda functions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) in order to understand some more advanced python topics

Comment: @Greg: `lambda x, y: x * y` does the exact same thing as `operator.mul` (which the OP says she already understands), except slower, more verbose, and easier to get wrong.

Comment: @StacyM: Whenever you find yourself doing `for idx in range(len(foo))`, especially if you end up doing `foo[idx]` inside the loop, it's usually simpler to just do `for idx, x in enumerate(foo):`. And even if you're not supposed to use `enumerate`, you can write your own version in one line, then use it, right? But here, of course, you don't actually need `idx` for anything at all, so…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is pretty much the same as for `in`. Note that you don't need to make a variable from the list length, also you don't need to specify a start for the `range()`, it's `0` by default.

```
def prod(L):
    p = 1
    for i in range(len(L)):
        p *= L[i]
    return p

print(prod([1,2,3,4]))  # prints 24
```

Comment: What if L is an empty list? Return 1?

Comment: @CT Zhu: Ah I understand your question here.  No, the degenerate case of *multiplication* is one: `numpy.ndarray((0,)).prod() == 1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [2,3,4,7]
>>> len(x)
4
>>> range(0,len(x))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> range(len(x))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> def prod(L):
...     p = 1
...     for i in range(len(L)):
...             p = p*L[i]
...     return p
... 
>>> prod(x)
168
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way how to solve it (up to max recursion depth) using `range`:

```
def prod (x):
    range (42)
    def prod_ (head, *tail):
        return head if not tail else head * prod_ (*tail)
    return 1 if not x else prod_ (*x)

print (prod ( [1, 2, 5, 19] ) )
```

Comment: How is this "using `range`"? Just calling it and ignoring the result doesn't do anything; you might as well just reference the function instead of calling it…

Comment: Just referencing it would be another option.

Answer (score 0):

Using `math` library allowed? That will be easy (doing it in `numpy` would be sort-of cheating):

```
>>> from math import *
>>> def prod(L):
        if 0 in L:
            return 0.
        #elif len(L)==0:
        #    return 0.
        elif sum([item<0 for item in L])%2==0
            return exp(sum(map(log, L)))
        else:
            return -exp(sum(map(log, map(abs, L))))
```

Comment: the product of an empty sequence (of numbers) should be 1, not zero.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. That actually makes thing easier, as `exp(sum(map(log, map(abs, []))))` also returns 1.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more fun to reduce this to set theory (e.g., via Peano arithmetic) instead of logarithms? You could cheat and just do multiplication as repeated addition, or you could go all the way down to `def succ(x): return {x, frozenset({x})}` and build from there.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that will be fun. Empty product is 1, empty sum is 0. Should have remembered all that fun intro set theory.